# MKMapView#visibleMapRect returns MKCoordinateRegion instead of MKMapRect (RubyMotion)

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit, rubymotion

According to apple documentation calling visibleMapRect should return an instance of MKMapRect but I am getting a MKCoordinateRegion instead.

```
 class MyMapController < UIViewController
  def loadView
    super
    self.view = MKMapView.alloc.init
    view.delegate = self
  end

  def viewDidLoad
    region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(
      CLLocationCoordinate2D.new(20.7103500366211, -101.607849121094),
      MKCoordinateSpanMake(18, 18)
    )

    view.setRegion region, animated: false
  end

  def mapView map, regionDidChangeAnimated: animated
    puts map.visibleMapRect.inspect
    # prints => <MKCoordinateRegion center=#<CLLocationCoordinate2D latitude=47967664.0 longitude=106401408.0> span=#<MKCoordinateSpan latitudeDelta=20971520.0 longitudeDelta=24051712.0>>
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you output the results of this: `MKStringFromMapRect(map.visibleMapRect)`? Also, `view.setRegion` should be `view.setRegion(region, animated: false)`.

Comment: Got this: `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:': expected instance of `MKMapRect', got `#<MKCoordinateRegion center=#<CLLocationCoordinate2D latitude=92274688.0 longitude=105827520.0> span=#<MKCoordinateSpan latitudeDelta=83886048.0 longitudeDelta=96206816.0>>' (MKCoordinateRegion) (TypeError)`

Comment: Did you change to the setRegion:animated: method?

Comment: I don't even know if it's an issue with RubyMotion, could it have to do with some typecasting? Am I talking nonsense?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me... submit a ticket to RubyMotion (`motion support` at the command line) and reference this Stackoverflow. They may be able to help you. Then put your answer here.

Comment: I did already, I don't have an answer yet. I've solved it converting the returned MKCoordinateRegion to MKMapRect (the span and origin are in map units, no prob). Yet it leaves me an uneasy feeling that things don't behave according to the official documentation.

Comment: You might check `map.visibleMapRect.is_a?(MKMapRect)` to ensure if it ever reverts to working properly that your app can handle it gracefully.

Comment: Yeah, that might be a good idea, although I don't know if there could be unconsistent behaviour on runtime or it's more of a compilation issue or even if it has anything to do with RubyMotion. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is a bug in RubyMotion:

> Hi,
>
> It is possible that this is a compiler bug. Both structures may have
>   the same signature (same field types) therefore the compiler gets
>   confused. We will investigate this for an upcoming software update.
>
> Regards. Laurent